# biblatex 'cited as' entry field for bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to add a biblatex entry field that if activated prints how something is being cited. So in the bibliography I'd have something like that: [image]

So the idea is, to have a dedicated entry field. "**howcited**" for example:

```
@COMMENTARY{beck.ok,
    MAINTITLE       = {Beck'scher Online-Kommentar BGB},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    EDITOR          = {Bamberger, Heinz Georg and Roth, Herbert and Hau, Wolfgang and Poseck, Roman},
    SHORTHAND       = {BeckOK},
    VOLUME          = {},
    TITLE           = {},
    YEAR            = {2018},
    EDITION         = {45},
    HOWCITED        = {1},
}
```

This field would act as a switch. If the entry would be "1", the field would print the following text first:

"(zitiert als:"

Then it would either take the `shorthand` entry and print it followed by "/*Bearbeiter*)"

So in the end I would be left with something like "(zitiert als: `shorthand`/*Bearbeiter*)"

See attached picture.

Any ideas how I can do it?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems more natural to me to define an entry option instead of a field with a throwaway value.

After we have defined the entry option `howcited`, you can enable the "howcited" feature with `options = {howcited=true},` or the short `options = {howcited},` in your `.bib` entry. Below the option is also implemented per-type and globally, so you enable "howcited" for all entries of type `@commentary` or for all entries at once without having to set the option in the `.bib` file. Since the macro checks for a `shorthand` before it does anything, you can probably set the option on a per-type basis:

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[commentary]{howcited}
```

That saves you the work of having to add the option to every entry in the `.bib` file.

The bibmacro-side of things is fairly straightforward and actually a bit of a rip-off of the `shorthandintro` macro in `biblatex.def`. Here I hooked the macro into `finentry`, but since you seem to have a fully customised style anyway, you may find a more elegant place for it.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{howcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \printfield{shorthand}%
          \setunit{\addslash}%
          \bibstring[\emph]{bearbeiter}}}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\finentry}

\NewBibliographyString{bearbeiter}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  citedas    = {zitiert als},
  bearbeiter = {Bearbeiter},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{beck.ok,
  maintitle = {Beck'scher Online-Kommentar BGB},
  editor    = {Bamberger, Heinz Georg and Roth, Herbert and Hau, Wolfgang and Poseck, Roman},
  shorthand = {BeckOK},
  date      = {2018},
  edition   = {45},
  options   = {howcited},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,beck.ok}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bamberger, Heinz Georg u.a., Hrsg. (2018). *Beck’scher Online-Kommentar BGB*. 45. Aufl. (zitiert als BeckOK/*Bearbeiter*).]

Comment: If I'd change this bibmacro to also print the author name. I'd use `\printnames{labelname}`. If I'd already defined the family name format like this: `\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{incollection}{%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
}{}%
}` how can I change the format to simpy `\emph` only for that howcited usage. I didn't want to open another question only for that. Because the rest is mainly the same.

Comment: @texnewbie There is no useful `labelname` for `beck.ok` that would be shown in the citations, so what do you want to add where? Since there seems to be additional code involved a new question makes sense to me. Please add a complete MWE with the relevant modifications.