Add Shorttitle to the end of the entry in bibliography
i am trying to add a shorttitle (or another field like usera) to the end of the bibliography.
Here my MWE:
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    oneside
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    style=ext-authoryear,
    firstinits=false
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \cite{author01}
    \cite{author02}
    \printbibliography[]
\end{document}

And the bib:
@book{author01,
 author = {John, Doe},
 year = {2015},
 title = {How to use BibLaTex the wrong way},
 edition = {12},
 publisher = {{Catoso}},
 subtitle = {BibLaTex for Dummys},
 location = {Denmark},
 shorttitle = {Biblatex wrong way}
}

@article{author02,
 author = {Mary, Doe},
 year = {2015},
 title = {How to use BibLaTex the right way},
 edition = {12},
 publisher = {{Catoso}},
 subtitle = {BibLaTex (not) for Dummys},
 location = {Denmark},
 pages = {835--854},
 shorttitle = {Biblatex right way}
}

Without:

With:

Is it possible to set the shorttitle to the last place in the entry? Do you have any ideas how to achieve that? Thank you!
Kind Regards,
Marc

With the standard styles and most third-party styles you can redefine the bibmacro finentry to add something to the end of a bibliography entry.
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    oneside
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, 
    style=ext-authoryear,
    firstinits=false
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibshorttitle}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield[bibshorttitle]{shorttitle}%
  \finentry}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{author01,
 author = {John, Doe},
 year = {2015},
 title = {How to use BibLaTex the wrong way},
 edition = {12},
 publisher = {{Catoso}},
 subtitle = {BibLaTex for Dummys},
 location = {Denmark},
 shorttitle = {Biblatex wrong way}
}
@book{author02,
 author = {Mary, Doe},
 year = {2015},
 title = {How to use BibLaTex the right way},
 edition = {12},
 publisher = {{Catoso}},
 subtitle = {BibLaTex (not) for Dummys},
 location = {Denmark},
 pages = {835--854},
 shorttitle = {Biblatex right way}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \cite{author01}
    \cite{author02}
    \printbibliography[]
\end{document}



Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443177/35864. If you need to discharge the finentry punctuation before the text you want to print, something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560417/35864 might be more useful.

Thank you very much! It works fine. Never thought it would be this easy, i don't know that you can use the command \renewbibmacro on finentry.
